# Android buttons at top and ScrollView at bottom of the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, uiscrollview

I have two buttons "Submit" and "Reset" on top of the ui and below this is my form. The problem is when i open my keyboard, the form scrolls up and goes below the top buttons layout. What should be the problem? I want to show buutons on top only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this
Replace to RelativeLayout to Linearlayout With orientation Vertical.

Comment: Change to Linearlayout first set orientation vertical then put your button then scrollview @beginner_android

Comment: Changing root RelativeLayout to Linearlayout is not making me open the keyboard and scroll is still going below buttons

Comment: actually what you need ?

Comment: Please refer the images

Comment: First Linearlayout then set code button and then put your Scrollview

Comment: Ahh!! atlast solved my problem.. Thanks :) @Jignesh Mavani

Answer (score 0):

you can try to prevent the keyboard from scrolling up your form, so the keyboard will be above your layout by doing this :

add this to your manifest

```
<activity 
    android:name="yourActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"/>
```

then put this inside your ScrollView

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="false">
</ScrollView>
```

if any trouble leave a comment !

Good luck

Comment: it is still scrolling up :(